# Windows BSOD loop: "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE" after repartitioning and installing Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, partitioning, bsod

Windows 10 x64 v1607 won't boot after I reprtition my single 1TB HDD and installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1 LTS amd64. it keeps doing a BSOD "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE".

My exact steps:

1. Boot from Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1 LTS amd64 on USB drive.
2. 'Try Ubuntu Gnome' option.
3. Shrink Windows partition from 850GB to ~= 350GB in GParted.
4. Move recovery partition (I have created a System Repair Disk) (also in 
   GParted)
5. Create new ~=350GB FAT32 Partition.
6. Use Ubuntu Gnome installer; use 'install alongside Windows' option. Installer succeeds.
7. Restart. Grub menu comes up, select Windows. Windows shuts down. I didn't see exactly what happened, but I came back and my PC was competely off. Turn back on.
8. Grub comes back, Windows again. Windows bluescreens with 'INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE'. Restarts. Automatic Repair fails. Restart.
9. Choose Windows at Grub again. Same bluescreen. This time no Automatic Repair - just shuts down.
10. Choose Ubuntu Gnome at grub. Boots successfully.
11. Restart, choose Windows. Again, bluescreen, no automatic repair.

I can access my Windows partition from Ubuntu Gnome. I created a Restore Point before I started the steps above. Can I use my Restore Point, and if so, how? Or should I use my recovery drive? Or get a fresh Windows image and reinstall?

Comment: Microsoft has some [tips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my disk had been converted to a Dynamic Disk somehow. This prevents you from having two boot partitions on one disk.

> #### Multi-boot environments
>
> If you're running a multi-boot configuration on a computer, you should not convert basic disks to dynamic disks. Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 2000 all support dynamic disks; however, you will cause problems if you upgrade a basic disk to a dynamic disk if you have all of these operating systems installed on the same machine.

Source: http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/tip/When-not-to-convert-basic-disks-to-dynamic-disks

I had to completely reinstall Windows using a recovery drive and gave up trying to dual boot; I just virtualised instead. I suspect dual-booting could still work, but I can't really be bothered to go through that. If anyone does have any experience in this, I'm sure that would be helpful for others with this problem, but, like I said, I don't want to do that.

If you has this problem, it is **almost** definitely because your disk is *dynamic*. It can be converted to basic but the disk must be emptied (cleaned and all volumes deleted) first. **If using option 2, 3 or 4 in the tutorial linked below, all data on the disk will be deleted, including the operating system(s). Backup any data you do not want to lose.** If using option 1, backup the drive anyway if it contains any important data.

How to convert a dynamic disk to a basic disk: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html